# How to reinit fastimage plugin each time the call ckeditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

Plug-ins are initialized the first call a tskeditor and fastimage plugin is initialized at this time. When I refer to this plugin a few times, it does not clear the previous selected image, even if I press cancel

How to reinit fastimage plugin each time the call ckeditor? Then it will work correctly

Comment: show what you have tried ?

Comment: Despite its name, the fastimage plugin inserts the whole image as base64 encoded data into the page, so in the end you get a much slower page for your users. It would be better for you to avoid that plugin and use normal images.